# Variable values stays even after reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, ejs

```
let quote;
let author;

// Get Method For The Root Route
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.render('home', {
        quote: quote,
        writer: author
    });
});

// Post Method For The Root Route
app.post('/', (req, res)=>{
    // API URL
    const url = 'https://goquotes-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/random?count=1';

    https.get(url, (response)=>{
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        // On Getting Data From API Parse It And Update Global Variables 
        response.on('data', (data)=>{
            const randomQuote = JSON.parse(data);
            quote = '" ' + randomQuote.quotes[0].text + ' "';
            author = '- ' + randomQuote.quotes[0].author;
            console.log(quote);
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
});
```

I am working with Node and ExpressJS. When I try this web application locally on my computer whenever I reload the page the variables quote and the author becomes undefined (that is what I want), but when I deployed my app on Heroku even after refreshing my page once a value is set to those variables they are remaining same and not becoming empty. I want it to work just like it works on my machine locally, any help would be appreciated

Comment: I don't know exactly what's happening here but, I would strongly suggest to avoid having global variables in your app. It leads to unexpected behaviour and makes it harder to test too.

Comment: you shouldn't use global variables, you can use [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) if you want

Comment: You need to store this information in a session if you want it to "persist" across multiple routes, otherwise saving is as a global variable will **not** work. Your API should be stateless.

Comment: @MohammedAlhila you cannot use `res.locals` in this case because those are two different controllers that are handling different routes. If one of them was a middleware function that runs prior the last function executed, then `res.locals` would be applicable here.

Comment: @goto1 yes thanks for that. exactly I was talking about the middleware

Answer (score 1):

They're defined in global scope, which means that they exist as properties of the global object in node (e.g. globalThis.quote and globalThis.author), which persists for as long as the application is running.

I assume that when you say that you reload your page locally, you restart your node script/application. However, when you upload your application and reload the page, you don't reload the application only the rendered page, which means that they will still exist.